# Refresh the list data while iterating over it in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to refresh/change the data contained in ArrayList while iterating over it.

Here is what I have written :

```
List<Message> msgList = getList();

if (msgList != null && msgList.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < msgList.size(); i++) {
        Message message = msgList.get(i);
        String msgType =  getMsgTypeFromId(message.getMessageId());

        if (msgType != null) {
            if (msgType.equals(MessageType.INCOMING.getType())) {
                // Do some operation
                msgList = getNewList(); // How to do this, Is it correct ?
                i = 0;
            }
        }
```

Let me know is it correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: @SeanBright At least, it doesn't look incorrect... but surely looks ugly like hell.

Comment: You can instantiate new List & copy the the items from previous to other.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi - I'm sure we've all written code we aren't proud of

Comment: @mithatkonuk In the worst case, IndexOutOfBounds if the new list is empty or NPE if the new array is null.

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` isn't possible either

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to tell us what you're trying to achieve with this. It looks a bit like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @SeanBright "IndexOutOfBoundsException isn't possible either" Yeap, I noticed.

Comment: Yes: it looks weird because your changing the list from inside the loop, but it should work.

Comment: @SeanBright " I'm sure we've all written code we aren't proud of" Occasionally, I might wear not-quite-clean underwear. No reason for me to show it publicly, though.

Comment: yes. I agree that code is ugly and has scope for refactoring BUT it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Some code reviewing:

```
List<Message> msgList = getList();
// just in case the getNewList() returns null
// check it here---V
for (int i = 0; null!=msgList && i < msgList.size(); i++) {
    Message message = msgList.get(i);
    String msgType = getMsgTypeFromId(message.getMessageId());

    // no need for cascading two ifs. I'm assuming
    // MessageType.INCOMING is a "constant" thus bound to never return null
    if (MessageType.INCOMING.getType().equals(msgType)) {
        // Do some operation
        msgList = getNewList();
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to check the size of msgList is > 0.

Comment: @user7 No need to separately check if msgList is null before the cycle either - but definitely need to check it in the test condition of the cycle (just in case the getNewList returns null).

Answer (score 0):

> Let me know is it correct?

Sometimes (most of the times) it's ineffective. You start processing from the beginning of list for each updated/deleted item. In worst case you have to view first element O(N) times, second element O(N-1) times etc.

ListIterator in java supports removal of current element and replacement of current element, also updates on element fields don't touch list itself and its iterators. So if your "some operations" only include update/removal/replacement of current element, you can do it without interrupting loop.

This way you can process whole list in one iteration.

If you need more wide operations over list (like add/remove other elements), follow @AdrianColomitchi example.